# How do I decide which Persistent Token to delete in Spring Security PersistentTokenRepository.removeUserTokens

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've implemented Persistent token based Remember Me with Spring Security 3.2.3.RELEASE.

During development and testing I realized the database is filled with tokens for the same username.

When removeUserTokens is called I don't know which of the tokens I need to delete. I guess that the user have multiple tokens, one for each device he's using (Computer, Android, etc...), and if he logs out of one device, I want to delete the token for that device so he stays logged in another device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change the `Authentication` object you use in such a way that calls to the `getName()` return **"deviceID"+"username"** instead of **"username"**.

You could for example hash HTTP header UserAgent and use it as a device ID. The call to `PersistentTokenRepository.removeUserTokens` will then always only remove tokens related to the particular device.

The value returned from the `getName()` call can be customized by changing logic in your `UserDetailsService` implementation, as the Authentication.getName() typically delegates to `UserDetails.getUsername()` of the object returned from the `UserDetailsService`.

Other possible solutions will most likely require custom implementation of the `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices` interface.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good, I'm gonna try and implement it. Why do you suggest to hash the user agent? I think it'll be better to have it clear in the DB, so it's easy to see the agent. What do you think?

Comment: Hashing would produce a fixed-length string. Using the user-agent data directly might look like a mess and might require more space for the field itself and indexes, as you'd need a larger database field (or trimming of the user-agent header value in case it happens to be too long - as maximum HTTP header length is typically around 8KB - of course nobody's usually using so long headers, but the application should be able to handle them correctly anyway). Hashing makes these (small) issues go away.

Answer (score 3):

1) create custom PersistentTokenRepository with one additional method:

```
public class MDJdbcTokenRepository extends JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl {
    public void removeTokenBySeries(String series) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update("delete from persistent_logins where series = ?", series);
    }
}
```

2) create custom RememeberMeServices

```
public class MDRememberMeServices extends PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices {
    private MDJdbcTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    public MDRememberMeServices(String key,
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            MDJdbcTokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        super(key, userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        setParameter("remember-me");// parameter name in login form
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) {
        cancelCookie(request, response);

        if (authentication != null) {
            String rememberMeCookie = extractRememberMeCookie(request);
            if(rememberMeCookie != null && rememberMeCookie.length() != 0) {
                String[] cookieTokens = decodeCookie(rememberMeCookie);

                if (cookieTokens.length == 2) {
                    String series = cookieTokens[0];

                    //remove by series
                    tokenRepository.removeTokenBySeries(series);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) add beans

```
private static String key = "your string here";
@Bean
public MDJdbcTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    MDJdbcTokenRepository db = new MDJdbcTokenRepository();
    db.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return db;
}

@Bean
public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() throws Exception {
    return new MDRememberMeServices(key, userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository());
}
```

4) change your security spring config:

```
and().rememberMe().key(key).rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie in this world of Spring but I hope I can give you a tip...

Taking a look at `PersistentTokenRepository` you can notice that the only way to get the remember-me token is by using the seriesId stored in the cookie of your local browser. That way, when you log out on that device you only remove the "token) (actually the entire entry) of the corresponding seriesId.

So my try is to recommend you to just log out your user in order to delete its associated token.

I really hope that helps!